# Start script to launch repeating child scripts?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome, bash, startup

I'm trying to get this looping script to run at boot.  If I add '#! /bin/bash", I can start it automatically from profile startup but then I can't get the child windows to behave properly. - What am I missing?

```
num=0
while (($num <= 10)); do
    gnome-terminal -x sh -c "obs --startstreaming; exec bash" &
    timestamp=$( date)
    echo "Started OBS in new terminal window at $timestamp"
    sleep 4h
    pkill -n obs
    timestamp=$( date)
    echo "Killed OBS @ $timestamp"
    ((num++))
#
done
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
num=0
while ((num <= 10))
do
    gnome-terminal -x sh -c "obs --startstreaming; exec bash" &
    timestamp=$(date)
    echo "Started OBS in new terminal window at $timestamp"
    sleep 4h
    pkill -n obs
    timestamp=$(date)
    echo "Killed OBS @ $timestamp"
    ((num++))
done
```

Here is the output of [`shellcheck`](http://www.shellcheck.net/) for your script:

```
In test.sh line 1:
num=0
^-- SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang.


In test.sh line 2:
while (($num <= 10)); do
        ^-- SC2004: $/${} is unnecessary on arithmetic variables.
```

Comment: Thanks. This does launch the script, fire up a new terminal with OBS running and streaming as expected but does not continue processing the while loop so OBS (which is slightly unstable in my environment) does not get killed & restarted.

(I set sleep to 30s instead of 4h to test..)

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify:  It does restart OBS but leaves the previously spawned terminals running.  Which is probably workable as I can cron a system reboot to clear them before they become a problem. - Thanks for your help!!

Comment: you could try to get the PID from the opened terminal and put a kill up for it too. no need to cron a reboot.